# Accessing form that's created via code

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a new form via code:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form parpokeru = new Form();
    parpokeru.ShowDialog();
}
```

How could I access the form to add new elements to it, for example, a button. Or I have to do it via code as well? If there's any other ways, please tell me, i'll be only happy.

Comment: There is a reason to not use the Form Designer?

Comment: @Steve no. I just don't really know how to use parent forms (I remember something about them).

Comment: Manually creating a form is just for simple situations or if there is a specific need to do so. You need to code the same lines that you find in the `InitializeComponent` call of your main form. If you really have to create a form with buttons, labels, textboxes or datagridview it is better to use the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add controls to `Controls` collection of form

```
Form parpokeru = new Form();
Button button = new Button {
    Text = "Click Me", 
    AutoSize = true,
    Location = new Point(20, 50) // provide position
};

button.Click += (s,e) => MessageBox.Show("Clicked!"); // attach event handlers
parpokeru.Controls.Add(button);
parpokeru.ShowDialog();
```

**BUT** that's not very efficient way. Create new custom form, and use designer to add controls to that form. Then simply instantiate it:

```
ParpokeruForm parpokeru = new ParpokeruForm();
parpokeru.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Specifying locations generally makes for poor layouts on a form, creating objects that can never be resized, etc.  Proper layouting involves simply placing all controls inside of some type of layout panel, rather than hard coding fixed location points.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is created via code - you have access it via code.
If it is created via designer - you can access it via designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Controls.Add`:

```
Form parpokeru = new Form();
parpokeru.Controls.Add(new Button());
parpokeru.ShowDialog();
```